# SharePoint 2013 - Getting the correct Display Template for Search result Items

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I downloaded the Default Item template from Display Templates -> Search directory, assuming that template controls that actual text for titles in search results, only to discover that it does not. It simply has....

```
_#=ctx.RenderBody(ctx)=#_
```

for each item.  This appears to be a wrapper for each Item.  But which display template allows us to actually change the title variable for search result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Item_CommonItem_Body.html" under Master Page > Display Templates > Search

```
<div id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + Srch.U.Ids.title) =#_" class="ms-srch-item-title"> 
    <h3 class="ms-srch-ellipsis">
        _#= titleHtml =#_
    </h3>
</div>
```

I searched for "ms-srch-item-title" class and there it was.